# How does rosdep install decide which packages to apt-get install?

Tags: rosdep, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running `rosdep install` on a clean machine it pulls down lots of packages from `apt-get` or whatever is installed. As far as I can determine, it is something connected with the `package.xml`, but sometimes a `<depend>foo</depend>` ends up installing `libfoo-dev`.

Where is the code that does this? Is there an option to `apt-get remove` afterwards as a Docker image won't usually need the `-dev` variants?

I would guess there isn't an automatic way to do this, but if I could find the logic I could cobble something together for my own needs.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318786/how-does-rosdep-install-decide-which-packages-to-apt-get-install?/) by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2019-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> When running `rosdep install` on a clean machine it pulls down lots of packages from `apt-get` or whatever is installed. As far as I can determine, it is something connected with the `package.xml`, but sometimes a `<depend>foo</depend>` ends up installing `libfoo-dev`.

Please see whether #q215059 and #q217475 answer your questions sufficiently.

> Is there an option to `apt-get remove` afterwards as a Docker image won't usually need the `-dev` variants?

No, there is no option for that (in `rosdep` at least), but package manifests should split out their dependencies in `exec` and `build` dependencies. If they do that properly, you could automate removing the build dependencies. Unfortunately this would also depend on the [rosdep db](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/tree/master/rosdep) containing separate keys for devel and runtime dependencies, which isn't always the case (and in addition on all platforms that you'd like to deploy to, to actually split dependencies such that they are different for build and run phases, which isn't always the case either).

> I would guess there isn't an automatic way to do this, but if I could find the logic I could cobble something together for my own needs.

You might be interested in taking a slightly different approach, seeing as you're already using Docker.

See the *Hermetic Robot Deployment Using Multi-Stage Dockers* presentation from ROSCon'18: [video](https://vimeo.com/293626218) ([slides](https://roscon.ros.org/2018/presentations/ROSCon2018_multistage_docker_for_robot_deployment.pdf)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on 2019-03-19**:
#q215059 has a lot of useful info. The slides look good too. Building our own distribution in one container then copying over the `/opt/ros/` directory to another and installing things until it stops breaking seems the way to go.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-19**:\

> Building our own distribution in one container then copying over the `/opt/ros/` directory to another and installing things until it stops breaking seems the way to go.

I'm not sure that is what the presenter means / they are doing. I believe the video of the presentation should clear things up a bit.